# Click picture and to go to another picture that's a link?

Tags: javascript

I'm using an `onclick` for two images, however, once the first picture is clicked, I want the second image to serve as a link to the next image. What I have right now is two pictures that switch back and forth.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Starting Your Journey</title>
    <style>
        a:link {color: #ffffff;}
        .image
        {
            text-align: center;
            border: 10px solid black;
            margin-left: -30px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-top: 80px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="  background-color:black;">
    <script>
        function changeImage()
        {
            element=document.getElementById('myimage')
            if (element.src.match("two"))
            {
                element.src="./choosingstarter.png";
            }
            else
            {
                element.src="./choosingstartertwo.png";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="image">
        <img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()" src="./choosingstarter.png">
    </div>
    <a href="../story_begin.html" style="text-decoration:none">Continue!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the second image

Comment: It looks like they're just swapping the src of the one image

Comment: Am I right that you want this to be kind of like a slideshow, with a new slide on each click of the one image?

Comment: Please, don't learn JS from W3Schools. Their tutorials are full of security holes, bad practices, and mistakes. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: "I want the second image to serve as a link to the next image." I think you meant to say that after showing the second image you'd like to go to the next page. I've adjusted the code posted in my answer.

Comment: yeah the code is perfect now. I just wanted a swap for the img src, and for the second image displayed to be a link. its for a project at school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code hides currentImage and shows the next one, or in your case it'll navigate somewhere else when all the images have been shown. instaed of an image you could add several DIV elements in the div with the id imgContainer, then hide and show these instead of an image. That way you only need one page to show all images with story text.

```
<html>
 <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Starting Your Journey</title>
<style>
.image{
  text-align:center;
  border:10px solid black;
  margin-left:-30px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-top:80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}</style>
</head>
<body style="  background-color:black;">
 <script>
 // bad practice to have variables in the global scope
 // but to wrap the whole thing up in an object would
 // make this example too complicated
 var currentImage=0;
function changeImage(){
    // get all the images in the div with the id imgContainer
    var imageElements=document.getElementById("imgContainer")
        .getElementsByTagName("img");
    // set current image to 0
    imageElements[currentImage].style.display="none";
    // go to next image by adding one to current image
    currentImage++;
    // if the current image points to an image that doesn't exist
    // like 3 where there are only 3 images (0 is the first one)
    // then all the images have been shown, you can reset currentImage
    // back to 0 or navigate to another page
    if(currentImage>=imageElements.length){
       // navigate to another page
       window.location="http://www.google.com";
       // do not continue executing next lines
       return;
    }
    // this would reset the currentImage to 0 when it's
    // higher than the amount of images
    currentImage =(currentImage>=imageElements.length)
        ?0:currentImage;
    // show the next image
    imageElements[currentImage].style.display="";
}
 </script> <div class="image" id="imgContainer" onclick="changeImage()"> 
 <img src="./choosingstarter.png">
 <img src="./another.png" style="display:none">
 <img src="./and_another.png" style="display:none">
</div>
<a href="../story_begin.html" style="text-decoration:none">Continue!</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It simply removes the first picture :/ could you guys explain your answers? All i need is the first picture to be clicked for the next, and that next picture be a link. If you could point me to a tutorial that'd be fine.

Comment: I've added comments and changed the code so it shows the next image.

Comment: Thank you..so much. This saved me a lot of time! yeah it works perfectly after i put in the name of my other image and link on top. I get it, its just i have nothing really to work with except for jumbled tuts from w3schools.

Comment: The mdn documentation of JavaScript might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript Then there is a lot of css to know, I use firefox with firebug. If you know how to use it it can save you some time. The error console, inspect element and typing commands/adding or overwriting functions in the console is what I use mostly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    function changeImage() {
    element = document.getElementById('myimage');
    if (/two/.test(element.getAttribute('src'))) {
            element.setAttribute('src', "./choosingstarter.png");
        }
        else {
            element.setAttribute('src', "./choosingstartertwo.png");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Exact same as the Code i gave you :/